# Tibco Spotfire cross table

Tags: spotfire

How to show last 3 month aggregated data when current month is selected in Cross table for Tibco Spot-fire?

Example : If i select Month = June, then need to show June Data Along with Prior 3 months aggregated data (March + April + May)

Comment: @FatimaSuleman- Please provide some sample data to understand the question better.

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be to create calculated column which stores Month Name as Number (so January would be 1, February 2, March 3, ....).

You create Document Property which selects the month (display Month, value Number). And inside Cross Table you can do something like:

```
([Month Number] >= ${Property}-3 and [Month Number] <= ${Property}).
```

Can't test this right now but it should give you what you're looking for or at least some start point.